# How to identify a german id card by using a RFID-Card-Reader (javax.smartcardio)?

Tags: java, rfid, smartcardio

Hello Twogether,

I am writing a Java-Application using the

> javax.smartcardio.*;

The uid (32 bit) of german id card is generated randomly at each access.
The atr (152 bit) stays the same.

Currently I take the uid of rfid cards and if it is a german id card the atr.

Is there a way to get more informations from Smartcards using smartcardio?

How can I improve the german id card identification?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there an AID you can check for?

Answer (score 1):

The ID of German ID card is unique and unchanged for every card. To access this unique ID (which is stored in a file), you have to establish `File-Read keys` after mutual authentication. The temporary ID is used as a card challenge for key derivation functions.
I am sure [IAS ECC v1](http://www.unsads.com/specs/IASECC/IAS_ECC_v1.0.1_UK.pdf) will help you.